# How to using the Accessibility API of Android for click Whats app's send button

Tags: android, accessibility, whatsapp

First of all I would like to thank my friend for reading one of whose posts I got the knowledge about Android accessibility tools. I am developing a college app which should have the facility to whats app students' records to their parents. When students' Whats App numbers are entered in a list view, then Whats App on all the numbers will start sending by clicking on one button. I know that to send Whats App, you have to click on send button of Whats App, but we want to do it automatically through the accessibility of Android. I am opening android accessibility successfully with the help of given code. Now my question is how can i use suffix so that accessibility service will be notified and performing send action.

```
  AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat rootInActiveWindow = AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat.wrap (getRootInActiveWindow ());

    // Whatsapp Message EditText id
    List<AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat> messageNodeList = rootInActiveWindow.findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId ("com.whatsapp:id/entry");
    if (messageNodeList == null || messageNodeList.isEmpty ()) {
        return;
    }

    // check if the whatsapp message EditText field is filled with text and ending with your suffix (explanation above)
    AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat messageField = messageNodeList.get (0);
    if (messageField.getText () == null || messageField.getText ().length () == 0 
        || !messageField.getText ().toString ().endsWith (getApplicationContext ().getString (R.string.whatsapp_suffix))) { // So your service doesn't process any message, but the ones ending your apps suffix
        return;
    }

    // Whatsapp send button id
    List<AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat> sendMessageNodeInfoList = rootInActiveWindow.findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId ("com.whatsapp:id/send");
    if (sendMessageNodeInfoList == null || sendMessageNodeInfoList.isEmpty ()) {
        return;
    }

    AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat sendMessageButton = sendMessageNodeInfoList.get (0);
    if (!sendMessageButton.isVisibleToUser ()) {
        return;
    }

    // Now fire a click on the send button
    sendMessageButton.performAction (AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLICK);

    // Now go back to your app by clicking on the Android back button twice: 
    // First one to leave the conversation screen 
    // Second one to leave whatsapp
    try {
        Thread.sleep (500); // hack for certain devices in which the immediate back click is too fast to handle
        performGlobalAction (GLOBAL_ACTION_BACK);
        Thread.sleep (500);  // same hack as above
    } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {}
    performGlobalAction (GLOBAL_ACTION_BACK);
}
 }

    if (!isAccessibilityOn (context, WhatsappAccessibilityService.class)) {
Intent intent = new Intent (Settings.ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS);
context.startActivity (intent);
 }
```

I am using following code for sending simple whats app message.

```
    send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            try {
                String suffix;
                suffix = String.valueOf(R.string.whatsapp_suffix);


                PackageManager packageManager = MainActivity.this.getPackageManager();
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
               
                if (i.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
                    MainActivity.this.startActivity(i);

                }
            } catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```